# How to access variables in other package

Tags: go, package, global-variables

How can I move my global variable to other package in Go?

like

```
package main
import "myapp/controllers"

var something string

func main(){ 
  something = "some text" 
}
```

Comment: And can we access a global variable declared in package main, inside another package?

e.g:

package main

import(
  ...
)

var  Log  Logger

func main(){

}

------------

package helper 
import(
  ...
)

func helpFunc(){
   main.Log  =  <do something>
}

Answer (score 13):

Just to add onto Daves answer, and another possible issue you were having.
Variable names need to be Start With A Capital Letter To Be Visible

```
package main
import "myapp/controllers"

var Something string

func main(){ 
  Something = "some text" 
}
```

Additonally, you might have issues if you module name in go.mod file is weird. In this example it should  look something like this

```
module myapp

go 1.16

require ()
```

Answer (score 10):

Like you want to have a globally accessible variable in your package `controllers`?:

```
package controllers

var Something string
var SomethingElse string = "whatever"

func init(){ 
    Something = "some text" 
}
```

And then you can do

```
package main
import (
    "myapp/controllers"
    "fmt"
)

func main(){ 
    fmt.Println(controllers.Something, controllers.SomethingElse) //some text
}
```

Comment: I wrote that wants a global variable in the controller?
I Need in main package.

Comment: @PatrykGtfo You need to add another package (let's call it x here), and put some global variables in there to be exported. When other packages need these variables, just import this package x.

Comment: @PatrykGtfo go does not have globals, go only has package level variables and variables created in main can't directly be used in other packages